# How to concatenate values from different lists together?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write code that will repeat for x values from one list, y values from another list, and z values from the last list. The list values would be from user input in a previous line of code. I want to concatenate these values into a single print statement.

The list values would be from user input in a previous line of code.

This is the original code:

```
NCACost = [123,234,345]
NCADepr = [23,34,45]
NCANBV = [100,200,300]
for x in NCACost:
    for y in NCADepr:
        for z in NCANBV:
            print(str(x) + ' - end=')
            print(str(y) + ' = end=')
            print(str(z))
```

What I wanted:

```
123 - 23 = 100
234 - 34 = 200
345 - 45 = 300
```

Comment: You have `print(str(x) + ' - end=')`.  You want `print(x, end=' - ')`.  "end" is a parameter to `print`.  You're making it part of the string.

Comment: Simpler and more Pythonic is `print(f"{x} - {y} = {z}")`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't want three nested loops.  That will end up printing 27 lines.  What you want is to use "zip" so the three lists are iterated in parallel:

```
NCACost = [123,234,345]
NCADepr = [23,34,45]
NCANBV = [100,200,300]
for x,y,z in zip(NCACost,NCADepr,NCANBV):
    print(f"{x} - {y} = {z}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need

```
import itertools 

NCACost = [123,234,345]
NCADepr = [23,34,45]
NCANBV = [100,200,300]

# first sample
for (a,b,c) in zip(NCACost,NCADepr,NCANBV):
    print(f'{a}-{b}={c}')
# second sample
for (a, b, c) in itertools.zip_longest(NCACost, NCADepr, NCANBV):
    print(f'{a}-{b}={c}')
# third sample
for i, value in enumerate(NCACost):
    print(f'{value}-{NCADepr[i]}={NCANBV[i]}')
```